# Module Federation. including angular into react

Tags: reactjs, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

Has anyone had any experience connecting the angular to react via module federation? And is there any option to throw some data from react to angular as a prop?

I tried to throw Props into the file where the angular application is mounted and do not understand how to access props in the app.component

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.